# how to add new data to yaml flie python

Tags: yaml

I have project about chatbot, now I would like to add new data anser my chatbot when it got new anser can some one help me TT
this is my code and my yaml file
https://gist.github.com/channo39mz/73c38e51ba75f924af3f1953a256ebbd

Comment: You need to show the code as text and not image.

Comment: OK I write my code in github and post it now